# Searching Tweets in Python

Tags: python, twitter

Have a look at the following code:

```
q = '#MentionSomeoneImportantForYou'

count = 100

search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q, count=count)
```

`#twitter_api` is predefined and is working fine.

```
statuses = search_results['statuses']

for _ in range(5):
   print "Length of statuses", len(statuses)
   try:
       next_results = search_results['search_metadata']['next_results']
   except KeyError, e: # No more results when next_results doesn't exist
       break

kwargs = dict([ kv.split('=') for kv in next_results[1:].split("&") ])
```

The last code throws an error that 'next_results' is not defined.

Where did I go wrong on this?

Comment: Have you checked the json that is returned to see if the structure matches your query?

Comment: No. How exactly do I do that?

Comment: print the response, it should be a json object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't get why you have to

```
next_results = search_results['search_metadata']['next_results']
```

while this line will return the same result in 5 times ?

Anw, "next_results" is not defined means that the line above hasn't been reached even 1 time.

How about

```
print search_results['search_metadata']
```

to see exactly how was the API's response ?

Comment: The logic is intuitive. This is the result:

>>> print search_results['search_metadata']

{u'count': 100, u'completed_in': 0.071, u'max_id_str': u'486716269945569280', u'since_id_str': u'0', u'refresh_url': u'?since_id=486716269945569280&q=%23MentionSomeoneImportantForYou&include_entities=1', u'since_id': 0, u'query': u'%23MentionSomeoneImportantForYou', u'max_id': 486716269945569280L}

Comment: so it's no 'next_results' here :) Maybe you want `next_results = search_results['search_metadata']['refresh_url']` ?

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly!

```
# Import unquote to prevent url encoding errors in next_results
from urllib.parse import unquote


q='#Ethiopia'


count = 100

# See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q, count=count)

statuses = search_results['statuses']

# Iterate through 5 more batches of results by following the cursor
print(search_results['search_metadata'])
for _ in range(5):
    print("Length of statuses", len(statuses))

    try:
        #print(search_results['search_metadata'])
        next_results = search_results['search_metadata']['next_results']

    except KeyError: # No more results when next_results doesn't exist
        break

    # Create a dictionary from next_results, which has the following form:
    # ?max_id=313519052523986943&q=NCAA&include_entities=1
    kwargs = dict([ kv.split('=') for kv in unquote(next_results[1:]).split("&") ])

    search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(**kwargs)
    statuses += search_results['statuses']

# Show one sample search result by slicing the list...
print(json.dumps(statuses[0], indent=1))
```